# Calculate the angle between two 3d vectors: Function always returns 89.1-89.9

Tags: 2d, 3d, unity, trigonometry

I have my own 2d game and I am attempting to calculate the angle between 2 GameObjects.

**My Problem:** My function that is meant to calculate the angle(direction) between 2 Vector3's doesn't appear to be correctly calculating the angle. It always returns a value thats between 89.1 and 89.9, its never any other value.

What am I doing wrong? Can you help me to get my function to correctly calculate the angle between 2 Vector3's?

```
float getAngle(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2) {

    // If p1 or p2 == Vector3.zero then this funciton wont work. What shd I do in this case?

    float coefI  = p1.x * p2.x;
    float coefJ  = p1.y * p2.y;
    float coefK  = p1.z * p2.z;
    float scalar = coefI + coefJ + coefK; 
    float magnitude1 = p1.sqrMagnitude;
    float magnitude2 = p2.sqrMagnitude; 

    Debug.Log (System.String.Format ("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", coefI, coefJ, coefK, scalar, magnitude1, magnitude2));
    return (Mathf.Acos ( scalar / (magnitude1 * magnitude2) ) * Mathf.Rad2Deg); // Always returns between 89.1 and 89.9 for some reason
}

void Update() {
    Debug.Log( getAngle (Input.mousePosition, transform.position) );
}
```

Comment: Log the value of the normalized dot product: `scalar / (magnitude1 * magnitude2)`. If one of the vectors is zero, simply return 0. It does make some sense for a simulation: the zero vector is aligned with any other 3D vector so.. in a way, their angle is zero.

Comment: @teodron so your saying to calculate the angle I shd log it and not use Acos?

Comment: No, try and see if you get some sensibly different dot product values that you feed to the acos function. If that's the case, i.e. they're pretty close as well, the vectors are indeed almost perpendicular and you should look somewhere where the function is called..

Comment: If you insist on writing your own dot product calculation, at least order the operations so that they can more easily be optimised to use [fused multiply-add](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation): `p1.x * p2.x + (p1.y * p2.y + (p1.z * p2.z))`

Comment: Does the FMA work with Unity's scripting language? Nice thing, I wasn't aware of it, but it does seem to be a bit of an overkill in this case. The OP's code looks like a theory-based implementation of a concept, and it has no mathematical flaws.. computationally-wise, that's the step they should take after getting rid of the central issue.

Comment: @teodron: Unity has several scripting languages; the one here is C#, based on MonoDevelop. C#'s *runtime* will have support for FMA when the consumer-grade CPUs support it better (first ones will be here in this year from AMD and next year from Intel; consumer-grade GPUs support it for a while now, which is important if you use GPGPU), but as usual the optimisation will not kick in for all but the most obvious cases until some time after that, so it's better to help the VM along. It's not like the "optimised" version is any harder to read ...

Answer (score 3):

`sqrMagnitude` is the vector length squared, but you need the vector lengths. Simple fix:

```
return (Mathf.Acos ( scalar / Mathf.Sqrt (magnitude1 * magnitude2) ) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
```

Of course you could just use Unity's angle calculation function: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html